# Rollback procedure insertion

Tags: mysql

I have a script finishing by a rollback. the script containing a procedure that insert data.

sample

```
START TRANSACTION;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MYPROCEDURE_INSERTDATA;
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE_INSERTDATA ..... -- INSERT DATA INTO TABLE X

MYPROCEDURE_INSERTDATA('ABC');

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MYPROCEDURE_INSERTDATA;

ROLLBACK;
```

I want to cancel/rollback the insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE & DROP PROCEDURE cause an auto-commit - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html

So you would need to start the transaction after creating the procedure & rollback before dropping it.